# how to search into json object, using html input field

Tags: javascript, html, json

i am trying to filter this json API, using regex... but i have problem which i can't resolve, i receive some json, my goal is this, when i  input some letter for example "j" in input field, i want to return author of quote for instance "jessie", but second parameter in renderYourData does not works... can anyone explain what i am doing wrong? or just link me some documentation about this occasion...

```
//my HTML looks like this:

 <div class="container mt-5" ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 m-auto">
                    <h3 class="text-center mb-3" style="color: rgb(10, 10, 10); font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;">
                        Search Characters Quotes by their names
                    </h3>
                    <div class="form-grup">
                        <input type="text" class="imput form-control form-control-lg"   title="Only Alphabets" id="search" placeholder="search">
                    </div>
                    <div id="match-list"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

//my javascript looks same

const search = document.getElementById("search");
const ResultHtml = document.getElementById("match-list");



 const request = async () => {
                const response = await fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes");
                const data = await response.json();
                renderYourData(data);

     }

     const renderYourData = (data, searchtext) => {
        const x= data.filter(film=>{
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchtext}`, 'gi');
            return film.author.match(regex)});


            function retquote(){
                ResultHtml.innerHTML =`<div class="some">${x.map(function(bra){
                    return `<p>${bra.author}</p>`
                }).join("") } </div>`
            }
             retquote();
    }


     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                request();          
     });

search.addEventListener('input',()=>renderYourData(search.value)) 

//error // Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: searchtext is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything correct apart from one crucial thing; when you call *renderYourData* you must provide **both** of the parameters.

From what I can see, you have two possible solutions:

Solution A is to call *request* every time the search input box is changed, as shown below:

```js
const search = document.getElementById("search");
const ResultHtml = document.getElementById("match-list");


 const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes");
    const data = await response.json();
    renderYourData(data, search.value); // This line was changed
};

const renderYourData = (data, searchtext) => {
    const x= data.filter(film=>{
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchtext}`, 'gi');
        return film.author.match(regex)
    });

    function retquote(){
        ResultHtml.innerHTML =`<div class="some">${x.map(function(bra){
            return `<p>${bra.author}</p>`
        }).join("") } </div>`;
    }
    retquote();
}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    request();          
});

search.addEventListener('input',request) // This line was changed
```

However, I would suggest going with solution B as it reduces the number of calls that need to be made to fetch the JSON data; instead of calling *request* every time the search box is changed, you can instead call it when the page loads (as you already do) but store the JSON data for later use, as shown below:

```js
const search = document.getElementById("search");
const ResultHtml = document.getElementById("match-list");

let data; // This line is new


 const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes");
    data = await response.json(); // This line was changed
    renderYourData(data, search.value); // This line was changed
};

const renderYourData = (data, searchtext) => {
    const x= data.filter(film=>{
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchtext}`, 'gi');
        return film.author.match(regex)
    });

    function retquote(){
        ResultHtml.innerHTML =`<div class="some">${x.map(function(bra){
            return `<p>${bra.author}</p>`
        }).join("") } </div>`;
    }
    retquote();
}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    request();          
});

search.addEventListener('input',()=>renderYourData(data, search.value)) // This line was changed
```

I hope this helps

Comment: unfortunate this not works for me same error // Uncaught ReferenceError: searchtext is not defined

Comment: I was able to recreate your error by removing the _searchtext_ parameter from _renderYourData_. Can you make sure that both parameters are there?

Comment: Please, sorry, i just now double check A solution and it's works nicely for me ! thanx :)